How did Middleton's Microcynicon survive the Bishop's Ban of 1599?
Microcynicon: Six Snarling Satires is an early work of satire by Thomas Middleton. It was one of the nine works specifically singled out for censorship, i.e. burning by the hangman, by the Bishop's Ban of June 1599. According to Wikipedia, "it was not reprinted again in the seventeenth century", which implies that it was reprinted later.
How did Microcynicon survive the Bishop's Ban? In other words, what was the later reprinting based on? A manuscript (now probably lost) or a printed copy that had somehow survived? Is the original printing from the late 16th century still available or are modern editions based on the reprint after the seventeenth century?
Michelle O'Callahan's Thomas Middleton, Renaissance Dramatist (Edinburgh University Press, 2009) mentions the burning after the Bishop's Ban but says nothing about how the text survived (pages 9–10).

According to Wendy Wall,

Copies of the original edition (STC 17154) are found in the Huntingdon and the Bodleian with no textual variants between them.

These are copies of the octavo edition printed by Thomas Creede for Thomas Bushell.
Wall also adds that

We are fortunate to have access to any copies of the first edition given that Microcynicon was burned shortly after it was published.

No manuscript seems to have survived. The two earliest reprintings Wall mentions are the following:

Dyce, Alexander, ed. Works. 1840. Volume 5.
Utterson, Edward Vernon, ed. Microcynicon. 1842.

Source
Wall, Wendy: "Microcynicon: Six Snarling Satires". In: Thomas Middleton and Early Modern Textual Culture, edited by Gary Taylor and John Lavagnino. Oxford University Press, 2007. Pages 465–66.
